# How can I solve that python print loop

Tags: python, loops

I want create loop below.. (in python)

```
            content_cnt = len(content)
            if content_cnt == 0:
                self.bot.send("%s \n %s " % (title, content[0]))
            elif content_cnt == 1:
                self.bot.send("%s \n %s %s" % (title, content[0], content[1]))
            elif content_cnt == 2:
                self.bot.send("%s \n %s %s %s " % (title, content[0], content[1], content[2]))
                           ...
            elif content_cnt == 20:
                self.bot.send("%s \n %s %s %s ... %s " (title, content[0] .... contecnt[20]))
```

How can I keep my code simple?

Thank you for your help.

I tried to manually write lengthy code.
That's very inefficient.

Comment: There's no loop here. Do you mean simply *conditional statements*?

Comment: `(title, *content)`…? `(title,) + content`?

Comment: first, if `len(content) == 0` , than is empty and that you can't even get `content[0]`
solution:
`self.bot.send(f"{title} \n {' '.join(content)}")`

Here we use:
1) Formatted string literals (also called f-strings) allow to use variables directly in the string. I find it easier to read than using %. [documentation][1]
2) ' '.join to join elements of content in a string, and seperate them by an empty space. [documentation][2] 


  [1]: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings
  [2]: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join